# forced checkin or checkout using NANT

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

Is there any way that NANT would do a force checkout from source control or force checkin even if there is newer version in source control?

Answer (score 1):

I not an nant guy, but could you explain what is the purpose of it?

Forcing checkin automatically looks to me like a bad idea - if I modified file by mistake I don't want it to be automatically checking without my innervation.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using a CruiseControl.NET source control block then you could specify cleanCopy="true" to delete the working copy before updating the source.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to circumvent the normal CruiseControl.Net checkout mechanism? You will have to execute the source control command line yourself, or use something like [NAntcontrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc3/help/tasks/index.html).

Please specify what source control engine are you using.